# TitlePageIndicator title becomes different from PagerAdapter.getPageTitle(int)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

The issue I'm noticing happens when the user scrolls to the next (or previous) page in the `ViewPager`, which triggers the `ViewPager`'s settling (confirm?) to that page. This works perfectly unless the user starts dragging while the `ViewPager` is still settling. In this scenario what I get is the title shown by the `TitlePageIndicator` shows the title for 2 pages after (or before, respectively) while the content shown by the `ViewPager` is showing the next (or previous) page.

If the user starts to swipe after that page - the one with the mismatched title and content - has settled, the title gets quickly updated to the correct title. Looking at [`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrollStateChanged%28int%29) they say "Useful for discovering when the user begins dragging, when the pager is automatically settling to the current page" for `onPageScrollStateChanged(int)`, which seems to be what the issue is, but I haven't found a way to use the method to resolve the issue.

I'm using Jake Wharton's `com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator` with `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` to render a view of calendar days. Swiping left/right moves to the previous/next calendar day. This means my `ViewPager` is set up to implement infinite pagination based on 3 `Fragments` that correspond to the visible day, the day before the visible day, and the day after the visible day.

My `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` is constructed like this and attached to the `TitlePageIndicator`

```
_title.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        private int _focused_page = _VISIBLE;
        private boolean _is_settling = false;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if (_focused_page == _PREVIOUS)
                    moveToPrevious();
                else if (_focused_page == _NEXT)
                    moveToNext();

                // always set to middle page to continue to be able to
                // scroll left/right
                if (_paginator.getCurrentItem() != _VISIBLE)
                    _paginator.setCurrentItem(_VISIBLE, false);
                _is_settling = false;
            } else if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING && _is_settling) {
                Ln.d("Double scrolled!");
                _title.setCurrentItem(_paginator.getCurrentItem());
                _title.invalidate();
            } else if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                _is_settling = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            _focused_page = position;
        }
});
```

I see there to be about 3 solutions

- Disable the sending or responding to user drag event while settling
- Notice when the drag occurs during a settling and recover the correct title after it becomes invalid
- Move the `ViewPager` with the second drag as if it were the first drag resulting in everything being 2 pages after (or before) the original visible day

**EDIT:**
Is there a way to force the `TitlePageIndicator` to call `getPageTitle(int)` again to redraw the title with the correct title?

Comment: Maybe consider filing a bug report? [ViewPagerIndicator Issues Tracker](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/issues)

Comment: Sure, I was wondering if it was a bug, or if someone had a way to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found a Solution, thanks to your first implementation.

```
private static final int PAGE_LEFT = 0;
private static final int PAGE_MIDDLE = 1;
private static final int PAGE_RIGHT = 2;

mTitleIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            private boolean isSettling;
            private int focusedPage = 1;

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                focusedPage = position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                if (sViewPager.getChildAt(PAGE_RIGHT) != null) {
                    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                        // User swiped in right direction, change to left page.
                        if (focusedPage == PAGE_LEFT) {
                            doSomething();

                            // User swiped in left direction, change to right page.
                        } else if (focusedPage == PAGE_RIGHT) {
                            doSomething();
                        }
                        mTitleIndicator.setCurrentItem(PAGE_MIDDLE, false);
                        isSettling = false;

                    } else if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING && isSettling) {
                        mTitleIndicator.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } else if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                        isSettling = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    mTitleIndicator.setCurrentItem(PAGE_MIDDLE, false);
                }
            }
        });
```

> EDIT: Is there a way to force the TitlePageIndicator to call getPageTitle(int) again to redraw the title with the correct title?

Yes, call `TitlePageIndicator.notifyDataSetChanged()` (which only call `invalidate()`).

**EDIT:** My solution only works when scrolled back, not forth.